# Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm doing Spring Security and I'm trying to connecte my API with database to get user Authentication. 
I don't know the error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

    Property: driverclassname
    Value: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
    Reason: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Action:

Update your application's configuration

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like HikariCP configuration issue. If you are using yml file for spring boot, the application.yml file should have the following contents.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: <jdbc url specific to your database>
    driver-class-name: <database url>
    username: <username>
    password: <password>
    hikari:
      idle-timeout: 10000
```

Please change the place holders as I have mention with angles <> as per the database.